# Assigning different Factories to a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, factory

I have multiple factories that take an int and return an Object of Type Creature:

```
public static Func<int, Creature>[] ForestEnemyFactory1 = new Func<int, Creature>[] 
        {
            (level) => (Creature) new Spider(level),
            (level) => (Creature) new Ogre(level),
        };

    public static Func<int, Creature>[] ForestEnemyFactory2 = new Func<int, Creature>[]
    {
        (level) => (Creature) new ArmourBug(level),
        (level) => (Creature) new GlowBug(level)
    };
```

The function that calls them is suppossed to be conditional in which one to call.

```
if (...) {
Enemy1 = ForestEnemyFactory1[x](y);
else
```

now I would like to have the function always call the same delegate, and decide elseswhere which one to call.

```
delegate Del = ...   
Enemy1 = delegate (int positionInArray, int level)
```

and then define elsewhere:

```
if (...){
   delegate = ForestEnemyFactory2;
```

But no matter how I try, I can't find a solution on how to define the delegate and have him accept one of the Factories. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Wouldn't it just make sense to have that "elsewhere" code pick up the real delegate and pass it, rather than double-hopping through another delegate

Comment: @Charlieface I'm not sure I understand, can you give me an example of how you would implement this?

Comment: TBH not sure I would do this in the first place: using a big `switch/case` against an array. I would probably have had something like a dictionary of strings (`Creatures`) and `Func`s. What I meant to say is that it sounds like you want **another** delegate just to get the correct delegate from the array. I think you just need to get the calling code to lookup the delegate from the array, and pass that through.

Comment: What you need is `Func<int, int, Func<Creature>> getCreature = (index, level) => () => ForestEnemyFactory1[index](level)` or a method `Func<Creature> GetCreature(int index, int level) { return () => ForestEnemyFactory1[index](level); }`

Comment: @user1344783 Thanks, this solved my question! Feel free to give this as the official answer!